# Recognition multiple occurence of an object by SURF descriptor

Tags: image-recognition, surf

My goal is to recognize and mark all occurence a test object in a image. 
I've been working on recognition object  using SURF descriptor. Currently, I'm able to extract descriptors from  object image and scene image and then match them through a Euclidean-distance based nearest neighbor approach. Then, a homography matrix( with RASNAC) is computed to localise and mark object in image scene. But I can't figure out how to mark an object if it occurs more than once in a image scene.?